# sql where in vs where >= AND <=

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a set of table rows based on ids.
The ids are contiguous (e.g 12001 - 13000)

Is it faster to do

```
WHERE id IN (12001, 12002, ...)
```

or

```
WHERE id >= 12001 AND id <= 13000
```

Comment: Who cares, pick one and move on. Surely this is a one off anyway

Comment: `>= AND <=` would be more clear for sql. And `between .. and ..` may be more better. I think you would not want to write 1000 ids in `IN`.

Comment: absolutely, id being an index will be extremely fast either way. I don't see a case for optimization here.

Comment: and you should hard code all values in `IN` ? query becomes large I think )

Comment: The easiest way is to test it. Run both queries and see which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

```
WHERE id >= 12001 AND id <= 13000
```

This where clause uses range, you just need to identify starting range to end / max range. While if you use the other option IN Clause, you need to identify every single ID then put it inside the IN clause

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Table_name SET Column_name=  500 WHERE Column_name=  = 15 AND id IN (5, 7, 10, 11, 16, 25);

Comment: This does not answer the question presented.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a hash index but not a b-tree index on `id`, the `IN` variant is probably faster. Otherwise, using `<= >=` or `BETWEEN` might be a bit faster, and much more readable in any case.